# Why I still can see the global ip after cancelling it

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I use below SL API to create/cancel/list global ips,

> The API endpoint is: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1
>
> Create: ProductOrder.PlaceOrder()
>
> Cancel: BillingItem.CancelService()
>
> List:
>   Account.GetGlobalIpv4Records()/GetGlobalIpv6Records()GetGlobalIpRecords()

I create one, then cancel it, but list will still show this IP record, it is just without billing item, is that expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep it is the expected behavior, softlayer runs a job proccess which starts the cancel proccess of all billing items (I think it runs once a day), but do not worry the billing item has been canceled and you will not be charged anymore for it (even if you use the Softlayer's control portal you will see that behavior).

Regards